# OwinStartup doesn't trigger in website deployed on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-web-app-service, dotnetopenauth

My problem is the OwinStartup only triggers once when the web app is published but subsequent visits to the URL results in infinite loop between the MS login page and my url. When I attached the remote debugger I see that the OwinStartup doesn't get triggered. But does so every time in localhost. I have read other threads and I don't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: `OwinStartup` is supposed to be only triggered once on your app startup and not on every request. I'm not sure I understand the question

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, triggering the OwinStartup very first time. The solution I found was to set

```
optimizeCompilations="false"
```

in web.config file.

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" optimizeCompilations="false" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```